# How can I remove leading and trailing whitespace from all columns but one in a CSV?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a CSV that looks like this:

```
things,ID,hello_field,more things
stuff,123  ,hello ,more stuff
stuff,123 ,hello ,more stuff
stuff ,123  ,hello ,more stuff
stuff,123  ,hello ,more stuff
stuff ,123,hello ,more stuff
stuff,123,hello ,more stuff
stuff ,123,hello ,more stuff
```

How can I remove leading and trailing whitespace from all columns except for the second (`ID`)? The final output would look like this:

```
things,ID,hello_field,more things
stuff,123  ,hello,more stuff
stuff,123 ,hello,more stuff
stuff,123  ,hello,more stuff
stuff,123  ,hello,more stuff
stuff,123,hello,more stuff
stuff,123,hello,more stuff
stuff,123,hello,more stuff
```

I tried using the following regex, but it removes spaces from *all* fields, including those in the `ID` column.

```
s/( +,|, +)/,/gi;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split, trim selectively, rejoin

```
perl -F, -lane 's/^\s+|\s+$//g for @F[0,2..$#F]; print join ",", @F' file.csv
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-F/pattern/`: `split()` pattern for `-a` switch (`//`'s are optional)
- `-l`: Enable line ending processing
- `-a`: Splits the line on space and loads them in an array `@F`
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each line in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `EXPR for @F[0,2..$#F]`: Iterate over array slice (skipping 2nd field)
- `s/^\s+|\s+$//g`: Remove leading and trailing spaces from fields
- `print join ",", @F`: Print the results

Comment: so @miller the syntax you have provided "@F[0,2..$#F]" will perform the substitution on the first, skip over '1', go to '2' and then the "$#F" performs it on all fields after until end of the file?

Comment: I think you've pretty much figured it out - let's see what @Miller says  :-)  Meanwhile see the [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) POD - specifically the autosplit section. Cheers

Comment: @miller, one more thing...it works well but instead of returning the delimiter it returns one of these....SCALAR(0x1dc19b4) any way to fix this?

Comment: you're printing a reference somewhere - something's messed up.

Comment: Fun one liner fact: with perl 5.20 using `-F` turns on `-an` automatically, so you can just use `-F, -le` - another reason to upgrade your perls!

Comment: hey @ysth I am trying to cut leading and trailing spaces within specific fields.  I am going to have to go with the one-liner due to the compactness.  Very easy to throw into a batch as a last clean up.  However the one problem as I mentioned is that instead of giving me my delimiter ',' it gives a output of "SCALAR(0x1dc19b4)" separating the fields..Anyone else experience this?  Also David W. the /x modifier is a great tip!!  Makes the regex more readable.  I assume I can combine with other modifiers?  i.e. /gix; ??  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @JDE876: The code in Miller's answer won't print that. You must show the actual code you are using

Comment: @BorodinI switched it up to tab delimited and I used this - perl -F\t -lane "s/^\s+|\s+$//g for @F[0,2..$#F]; print join "\t", @F" - Knowing that Miller had provided me with mac syntax, I attempted to switch it to PC using "\t", instead of '\t', to indicate a literal tab.  So when I switched to perl -F\t -lane "s/^\s+|\s+$//g for @F[0,2..$#F]; print join '\t', @F"  it worked beautifully.

Comment: @JDE876 To work on a windows machine, I'd use the following: `perl -F/\t/ -lane "s/^\s+|\s+$//g for @F[0,2..$#F]; print join qq{\t}, @F"`

Comment: I am glad you posted this @Miller. For a long time I have assumed that `s/\A\s+|\s+\z//g for @a` was a slower option than something like `do { s/\A\s+//; s/\s+\z//g } for @a`. I have just done the bench, and the alternation is actually 50% faster than the double operation (i.e. the first strips three strings in the time that the second strips two) so either the regex engine has had a lot of love and attention in that area or I dreamed my original assumption. Either is possible

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `awk`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if (i != 2) { sub(/^[ \t]+/, "", $i); sub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $i) } } 1' file
```

#### Output:

```
things,ID,hello_field,more things
stuff,123  ,hello,more stuff
stuff,123 ,hello,more stuff
stuff,123  ,hello,more stuff
stuff,123  ,hello,more stuff
stuff,123,hello,more stuff
stuff,123,hello,more stuff
stuff,123,hello,more stuff
```

#### What it does:

- Sets field separator and output field separator to `,`.
- Traverse the field values. If field number is not 2, trim out leading and trailing spaces.
- Print.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify each field in the substitution:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

for my $line ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ s/^\s*(\S+)\s*,   # Things: trim off the spaces
        (.+?),                # ID: Leave alone
        \s*(\S+)\s*,          # Hello Field: trim off spaces
        \s*(\S+)\s*           # More things: trim off spaces
        /$1,$2,$3,$4/x;
    say $line;
}

__DATA__
things,ID,hello_field,more things
stuff,123  ,hello ,more stuff
stuff,123 ,hello ,more stuff
stuff ,123  ,hello ,more stuff
stuff,123  ,hello ,more stuff
stuff ,123,hello ,more stuff   
stuff,123,hello ,more stuff
stuff ,123,hello ,more stuff
```

Here, I'm using `x` on the end of the regular expression which allows me to break the expression onto multiple lines.

This produces:

```
things,ID,hello_field,morethings
stuff,123  ,hello,morestuff
stuff,123 ,hello,morestuff
stuff,123  ,hello,morestuff
stuff,123  ,hello,morestuff
stuff,123,hello,morestuff   
stuff,123,hello,morestuff
stuff,123,hello,morestuff
```

I was thinking about using named capture groups. They're good if you are moving things around and you have lots of capture groups. However, in this case, I don't believe it makes things any easier to read:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

for my $line ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ s/^\s*(?<things>\S+)\s*,       # Things: trim off the spaces
        (?<id>.+?),                         # ID: Leave alone
        \s*(?<hello_field>\S+)\s*,          # Hello Field: trim off spaces
        \s*(?<more_things>\S+)\s*           # More things: trim off spaces
        /$+{things},$+{id},$+{hello_field},$+{more_things}/x;
    say $line;
}

__DATA__
things,ID,hello_field,more things
stuff,123  ,hello ,more stuff
stuff,123 ,hello ,more stuff
stuff ,123  ,hello ,more stuff
stuff,123  ,hello ,more stuff
stuff ,123,hello ,more stuff   
stuff,123,hello ,more stuff
stuff ,123,hello ,more stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer @Miller's answer which uses regular expressions as the OP requested, but there is also [`Text::Trim`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Trim) when needed:

`perl -MText::Trim -F, -anE 'trim for @F[0,2..$#F]; say join ",", @F' test.csv`

or:

```
use Text::Trim;
for (<>){
  my @line = split(/,/);
  trim for @line[0,2..$#line];
  print join",", @line, "\n";
}
```

I hope I'm not hijacking the thread, but I'm trying to explain to myself why `Text::Trim` works here but `String::Util qw/trim/` does not. And, more to the OP's question, why one works just like applying an `s//` (i.e. an expression) to the iterated value and the other doesn't. I think it has something to do with modifying the original value of the string. *i.e* the `String::Util` version of `trim` is  more akin to using the post **5.14** "non destructive substitution flag" a.k.a. `"/r"`**:** `s/^\s+|\s+$//rg` where as `Text::Trim` trims more directly ...

In any case `Text::Trim` uses this regexp:

```
s/\A\s+//; s/\s+\z// ;
```

(along with `wantarray` etc.) where as `String::Util`'s `trim` sub is errm different ... perhaps that's useful here ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Although i have stored the stuffs in the variable, but you can use it as you want. So, try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str="things,ID,hello_field,more things
stuff,123  ,hello ,more stuff
stuff,123 ,hello ,more stuff
stuff ,123  ,hello ,more stuff
stuff,123  ,hello ,more stuff
stuff ,123,hello ,more stuff
stuff,123,hello ,more stuff
stuff ,123,hello ,more stuff";

$str=join("\n",map{my ($a,$b,$c)=($1,$2,$3) if($_=~/(.*?),(.*?),(.*)/is);$a=~s/^\s*|\s$//sg;$c=~s/\s*,\s*/,/sg;$_=join(",",$a,$b,$c);$_} split /\n/i,$str);

print $str;
```

Output:

```
things,ID,hello_field,more things
stuff,123  ,hello,more stuff
stuff,123 ,hello,more stuff
stuff,123  ,hello,more stuff
stuff,123  ,hello,more stuff
stuff,123,hello,more stuff
stuff,123,hello,more stuff
stuff,123,hello,more stuff
```